# hasNext() makes for loop run endlessly, why?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

can somebody explain, why does this loop run endlessly?
I thought that the boolean **hasNext() ** is only true if there are no elements anymore. So when I type something in the loop runs like I typed something that goes endless too.
And what are these nmbers? please explain

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vocabulary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner standardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; standardInput.hasNext(); i++){
            System.out.print(i);

        }

    }

}
```

I researched in Internet about hasNext(). I know what it makes and I know how the for-loop works. But I don´t know why hasNext in for-loop makes the programm run endlessly.

Edit:

On the other hand, this code works. Why does this code work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        Scanner standardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double sum = 0;
        
        while(standardInput.hasNext()) {
            double nextNumber = standardInput.nextDouble();
            sum += nextNumber;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum is " + sum + ".");

        }
 }
```

Comment: For the fun of it on my Mac I ran your program as `java Vocabulary </dev/null`. Since you can’t read any input from `/dev/null`, your program terminated immediately without giving any output.

Comment: I do not understand that. It was explained to me that "hasNext()" looks if there are elements left. Oka, but what about the while loop? while(standardInput.hasNext()). But it works with while loop?

Comment: In a loop with a condition, you will need to do something to change the condition within the loop, or it will either run infinitely or not at all (your condition is `standardInput.hasNext()`). This is a rule in all programming.

Comment: A `while` and a `for` loop would be the same here.

Comment: Why do you say there is no output in this program, just type something in the terminal and press Enter. After that you will get strange numbers I don´t know. I get something like this: 5228465532846554284655528465562846557284655828465592846560......%

Comment: If you don’t know the Unix shell, just ignore my comment about what I tried (I am telling the truth about my observation, but it wasn’t important).

Comment: @Tilatila From [documentation of `hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()): "*Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.*". And that is the case with `System.in` which if not closed may still supply some data since user may be *in the middle of creating/writing it in console* and not yet pressed enter.

Comment: Your second program, the one where you say *this code works*, how are you stopping it? On my computer it just waits for input infinitely, and no matter how many numbers I type, it never prints the sum and exits. In any case, the difference it that within the loop you *are* consuming input from the scanner, so the next time through the loop it is at a new position, and once it’s read all the numbers entered, it needs to wait for new input before it can decide whether it has a next token. You are obeying the rule I gave: inside the loop do something that may change the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

`hasNext()` returns `true` if there is something waiting on the `Scanner standardInput` for being picked up. But you never pick it up, so it stays there and waits – endlessly, same as your loop.

Comment: I believe there is more obvious reason why TC have asked the Q: he have forgotten to call next/nextXXX in loop body.

Comment: What else does "you never pick it up" mean? That call to `nextXxxx()` does that "picking up" …

Answer (score 1):

`standardInput.hasNext()` is always true which is why you have an infinite loop.

`hasNext()` only checks if there is another token in the scanner and never moves from the start. For example when putting in the string "StackOverflow", the next token is always "StackOverflow".

One problem with using `hasNext()` in your case is that using Scanner halts the program and waits for an input, so it's always true so long as it has taken an input.

In this case, it looks like you're trying to iterate over the length of the scanner input and print the current character count each time - it might be better to assign the output of `nextLine()` to a variable and iterate over that instead. See below for an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Vocabulary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner standardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = standardInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Scanner hasNext:" + standardInput.hasNext());  // we can see that hasNext pauses our program

        for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
StackOverflow
hasNext
Scanner hasNext:true
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much. Can I ask you, I edited my Question und put another code with a while loop. In this while-loop I have the same standardInput.hasNext(). But this code works. What is different, I mean why does this not go infenitely?